# Implication of physical access to a hard drive with Bitlocker enabled but without TPM

Tags: windows-10, security, bitlocker, tpm, physical-security

I have a Windows 10 machine (fully updated as of 2019-10-23) in a work place that I leave at work at the end of the days. I have enabled Bitlocker for the main OS drive which houses some personal data. The machine however doesn't have TPM.

> If the computer is powered off and someone physically removes the drive, what kind of data can they access from it?

Comment: What type of key protectors are being used to secure the drive? Run `manage-bde C: -status` and put that info in your post.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Will update as soon as I have access to the computer again.